# Algorithm to search the numbers whose difference between each other is smaller than a fixed value?

Tags: algorithm, difference

Imagine there exits a huge real data set: A1,A2,A3,...,Ai,...An (where n is a very large number.). I want to find these subdata sets, in which the difference between each number within the these subset is smaller than a fixed value B. And it has to cost as little time and ram as possible. Any idea?

Comment: It sounds like some variation of bucket sort could solve the problem. However, the subset selection rules are inadequately specified to give a definitive answer.

Comment: I would sort the data and then do a linear pass through the sorted data to identify the subsets.

Comment: OK so you have three numbers 0, 2 and 4 and the difference should be less than 3. How do you group them?

Comment: The crucial question is what you want to optimise the grouping for. The largest group? The fewest groups? Or something else?

Comment: I will choose the group which has the Maximum number。

Comment: @n.m. 0 and 2 are one group; 2 and 4 are one group.

Comment: So you put 2 to both sets, right? What if you have (0, 1.95, 1.96, 1.97, 1.98, 1.99, 2.00, 2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.04, 2.05, 4)? Would you put all numbers 1.95..2.05 in two sets?

Comment: @n.m. For my need, yes, I will do that. But I can control the fixed value B to meet my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how much data did you mean - Is it small enough to load all data into RAM, whether it's 32 bit integer or not, how likely there are duplicates in your data, whether you'are using multiple machines or not and/or using map-reduce jobs etc. Despite lack of information, I can blindly suggest you to go with [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). Its linear time sorting algorithm.

### Edit 1

As you mentioned the data is already sorted in ascending order so we can find all subsets using binary search(upper bound) for each element.

Assuming the data container is `A[i]` and size `n`, here is the rough pseudo-code:

```
upper_bound(start, end, key):
    indx := end + 1
    while start <= end do
        mid := start + (end - start) / 2
        if A[mid] >= key:
            indx := mid
            end := mid - 1
        else
            start := mid + 1

     return indx
end


subsets := [] // list of subsets
for i = n - 1 to i = 0 do
    indx := upper_bound(0, i - 1, A[i] - B)
    set := [ elements from A[indx] to A[i] ]
    subsets.push(set)
end

print subsets
```

For each element `arr[i]`, you have to find upper bound; the overall time complexity is `O(n logn)`.

If you want, I can provide the C++ or Java working snippet.

### Edit 2

Here is the Java code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author kaidul
 */
public class Test {

    private static int upperBound(int left, int right, int key, Integer[] A) {
        int indx = right + 1;
        while(left <= right) {
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
            if(A[mid] > key) {
                indx = mid;
                right = mid - 1;
            } else {
                left = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return indx;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int B = 4;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = A.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            int startIndx = upperBound(0, i - 1, Math.min(A[i] - B, A[i] - A[0]), A);
            if(startIndx < i) {
                ArrayList<Integer> solutionSet = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( Arrays.copyOfRange(A, startIndx, i + 1) ) );
                result.add(solutionSet);
            }
            if(startIndx == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        result.stream().forEach((subset) -> {
            System.out.println(subset);
        });
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[7, 8, 9, 10]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: It is small enough to load into RAM, and it is long type, and no duplicates. For the machine, I only use my laptop.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to use Java. Could you be more specified? Or maybe the Java working snippet?

Comment: what does this means "    set := [ elements from A[indx] to A[i] ] and 
    "subsets.push(set)"? you are writing in Java or C++?

Comment: @lsl Check the final edit. Let me know if this is the output you're expecting. Or I will update again if you have different requirement.

Comment: @Kaidual    Thanks, that is exactly what I want. Well, actually, I have two this kind of data set A1, and A2. They are two set of times, that is A1=[t1,t2,...,ti,...tn] and A2=[T1,T2,...,Tj,..,Tm]. Now I want to obtain these time pair data set that ti and Tj are as close as possible. That is I want to have these sub set a[ti,tj,tl,...,Ti,Tj,Tl,...], the difference between each other should smaller than a fixed value B, and the these sub data set have to contain A1 and A2 element.

Comment: @lsl You're welcome. Accept this answer if your problem is solved. And don't forget to check the latest update of this answer as I've edited a small bug just a moment ago. And if your real problem won't solved with this, open a new thread and let me know. I will help if I can :)

Comment: This is much more complex than necessary. See my answer for a simpler method.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, the set is already sorted. Lets call the i-th element a[i]. A simple linear pass finds all subsets (pseudocode, without check for the end of the data - this is easy to add but would obscure the idea of the algorithm):

```
low = 0;
high = 0;
repeat {
    while (a[high] - a[low] <= B) {
        high = high + 1;
    }
    output set a[low .. high-1];
    while (a[high] - a[low] > B) {
        low = low + 1;
    }
}
```

Note that only the section between `low` and `high` needs to be in memory at a time. So it is possible to stream through the data without storing it all in memory.

This algorithm will also output one element subsets. If this is not wanted it can be easily suppressed.

Comment: +1 for sliding window like solution. "Note that only the section between low and high needs to be in memory at a time" - this space is not less than `O(n)` in worst case.

Comment: @KaidulIslam Correct. The actual space needs depend on the characteristics of the data. I assumed, that for practically interesting data sets it would be smaller than `n`.